# Using Pundit for authorizing controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I am learning to use Pundit for authorization. But the way I see it is authorization for resources not pages. I want a user to be redirected to a unauthorized page if he/she is not authorized to visit the page using pundit.

For e.g.

```
class OnlyAdminCanVisitController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :admin_authenticate
```

Stops a non-admin role user.

Also, I want to take care of made up scenarios like following(Considering there are 4 roles as Admin,Manager,Employee,Outsider. The design below is obiviously bad)

```
    class AdminManagerCanVisitController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :admin_or_manager_authenticate

    class AdminEmployeeCanVisitController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :admin_or_employee_authenticate

   class AdminOutsiderCanVisitController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :admin_or_outsider_authenticate

    class AdminManagerEmployeeCanVisitController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :admin_or_manager_employee_authenticate
```

I have 4 roles and would like to write pundit policies for these controllers which allows any combination of authorizations.

Let me know if pundit is designed to tackle this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not much difference between pages and resources actually. So you can solve your problem by rescuing a denied Authorization from your `application_controller.rb` :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  protected

  def admin_authenticate
    authorize current_user, :admin?
  end

  private

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
    # Redirect to whatever page you want if not authorized
  end
end
```

You then need to define your policy. I generally create an `admin?` method in `application_policy.rb` (https://github.com/elabs/pundit#policies) so it is spread on my other policies as well :

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  def admin?
    # Logic to ensure the user is an admin
  end
end

class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
end
```

Then in your other controllers, just do as you did :

```
class OnlyAdminCanVisitController < ApplicationController
  before_action :admin_authenticate
end
```

Comment: Thanks..It solves half of my problem. The other half is if I have 4 roles there 4! combination of authorization for example 2 out of 4 are eligible or 3 out of 4 and i cannot have a authenticate function for each of these combinations...let me know if i missed something..

Comment: Ok. Could you please update your post with your code related to roles so it's more clear to see the issue. It will depends on how you design the combination user/role Thanks

Comment: The policy rule apply for the User object. How did you design your role at the model/database level?

Comment: Role is a table and has a many_to_many relationship with the User through a user_roles table

Comment: Then this is simple. Inside your policy file (`UserPolicy` or `ApplicationPolicy`) create has much rule (like `admin?`) as you need. To stay DRY inside your controller, you could use a `concern` or wrap an utility function to handle roles to check for. My example is based on one role, but the same can be applied to many roles.

Comment: Thanks you are right may be i don't have to provide different authenticate function and they can be handled at one place..